# How can I represent file size in a human readable way in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

Let's assume that I have in html `*ngFor="let cell of dateFormat(row)">{{cell | filesize}}</td>` and `dateFormat` looks in this way

```
dateFormat(row:string){

    var today = new Date(row[4]);

    let latest_date = this.datepipe.transform(today, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    row['4'] = latest_date;

    return row;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of this.UploaderService.tableData2.dataRows">
    <td [ngClass]="{'active': check(row) }" (click)="listClick($event, row)"
       (dblclick)="listDoubleClick($event, row)"
       *ngFor="let cell of dateFormat(row)">{{cell}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

Is there any way to call [filesize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesize) only on `row['2']`? At the moment [filesize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-filesize) works properly however it formats all of the rows. I tried in `dateFormat` but I am not sure how can i use `filesize` in typescript . Something like this

```
let latest_date = this.datepipe.transform(today, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

row['4'] = latest_date;
row['2'] = here convert row['2'] using filesize;

return row;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using some grid system or a table, you'll need to add some source code to your question.

Comment: @HDJEMAI I added HMTL code. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
npm install ngx-filesize
```

In your module:

```
import {NgxFilesizeModule} from 'ngx-filesize';



// ...

@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        // ...
        NgxFilesizeModule,
        // ...
    ]
    // ...
})
```

In Your component

```
{{bytes | filesize}}
```

*I know this solution waa a late reply but it could help for upcoming developers :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have all of your code, so I'm creating an example with just dummy data,

so you can do something like this:

```
*ngFor="let cell of dataRows">{{(row == 2)? (row | filesize): row }}
```

For a demo, refere to [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-size-pipe-ggtzuj?file=src/app/app.component.html)

In this case, the `filesize` will be applied only when `row == 2`

Comment: But I need to display cell not row. Furthemore, I need to have date formatting like in the example `*ngFor="let cell of dateFormat(row)">{{cell}}` Everything works fine but I can't format file size.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what do you mean?

Comment: you have to provide your cell data and all your functions used in the template that can some one help you

Comment: Is it possible to use filesize in typescript in this place `row['2'] = here convert row['2'] using filesize;`?